# Async Queue - not waiting

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

I have an async function that fetches the reach from the Facebook API.

I've 'tried' to make it wait till it the server responds and then pushes the data.

However, it doesn't look like it's waiting. Am I using the `await` function correctly? Or shall I use another function?

```
async function(package) {
  var accessToken = "XXXXXXXXX"
  for (var v = 0; v < package.length; v++) {
    var postid = package[v].id
    var uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/" + postid + "/insights/post_impressions_unique?access_token=" + accessToken
    const response = await rp(uri);
    var dataParsed = JSON.parse(response);
    var reach = JSON.parse(dataParsed.data[0].values[0].value);
    console.log(reach)
    postsToProcess.push(reach)
  }
  console.log(postsToProcess)
}
```

`console.log(postsToProcess)` returns null

Comment: What does function rp() {} look like?

Comment: To use the await keyword your rp function must return a Promise

Comment: @dpolicastro and it does. But there seems to be a race between which promise is resolved first and with the console.log reporting an unexpected winner. Why is that? worth a look? Only missing code is the rp function.

Answer (score 0):

i saw a comment but it went missing when i refreshed the page.
basically it said if the for loop ran, this code ->  `postsToProcess.push(reach)` will throw an error before this code -> `console.log(postsToProcess` prints null.

Check if you are passing a valid array(package) with data to the function. Thats all i can think of. hope it helps.